# How to distribute a set of numbers across lists

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I am new to Haskell and i'm trying to solve a certain problem:
`distribute:: Int → Int →[Int]→[[Int]]`

`distribute 3 4 [1,2,3,4,5] ---> [[1,4],[2],[3]]`

i'm not sure how to accomplish this

distribute receives a number of lists in this case 3, a number of intgers 4 and a number list. Integers are then to be taken from the number list , individually and in sequence. That means list 1 St1 gets the first (1) from from the intger list , the second list the number 2, up to the the third list . This is repeated until all stacks contain 4 numbers.

distribute n m xs returns n lists that have m elements from xs distributed through them.

Comment: "i'm trying to solve a certain problem" - so what _have_ you tried? What code have you written and where exactly are you facing issues? Also, what is this function supposed to do?

Comment: It is much easier with an explicit specification, thanks. So you could start with: `distribute sublistCount maxIndex xs = map makeSublist [0..(sublistCount-1)] where makeSublist i = ...` . Thus your problem is now to write the `makeSublist` auxiliary function. As the selection criteria are about element indices not element values, you could start by numbering the list elements, as in `pairList = zip xs [0..]` ; you can then filter the pairs of interest for a given sublist, and as the last step ditch the indices, with something like `map fst pairList2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
distribute 3 4 [1,2,3,4,5] = [[1,4],[2],[3]]
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out a more general solution and couldn't understand what the function was supposed to do for other inputs.  Your answer avoids this issue, bravo.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson `distribute n m xs` returns `n` lists that have `m` elements from `xs` distributed through them.  It's a cool homework problem.  But this is clearly the correct answer for the question as asked.

Comment: @Carl how can one recursively create a discrete number of lists in a function

Comment: @qr3ck See the `replicate` function for an example of how to do that.